# Cooking water spinach safely

Tags: food-safety

Apparently water spinach (kangkung) has a parasite as it grows in water. How does one cook it safely to ensure that all the parasite eggs/cysts are no longer viable? I worry that with frying they could still be alive inside the hollow stems. Is there a specific amount of time that it must be cooked? Cleaning the chopping board and counter with just soap and water is okay?

Comment: surprisingly, there's not much information on that; only references that says to blanch it or cook it "long enough" to make it safe.

Comment: @Max thank you. I boiled it instead of frying and will fry garlic to add to it. I used to eat it all the time in Indonesia (with sambal) but didn't prepare it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water spinach, like other delta-grown crops, is host to [a variety of parasites that can infect humans](https://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/food/news/2014/01/15/kangkung-can-kill-you-hazards-and-health-benefits-of-a-noxious-weed).  You should [wash it in several changes of water](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/water-spinach-recipe-1969321); additionally some of my cookbooks (such as Asian Greens) recommend splitting the hollow stems to make sure they are clean on the inside.  Some sources recommend [soaking it in salt water](https://www.nutrition-and-you.com/kangkong.html) as well.

After that, it makes sense to blanch or steam water spinach for a couple of reasons; it kills any remaining parasites, and when frying raw water spinach without blanching, the stems tend not to cook all the way through.